# How PubNub publish subscribe works internally in iOS (client side)

Tags: ios, pubnub

I wanted to know what technology it uses to deliver real time messages iOS given all the os limitations. There are few of them comes to my mind are

- Periodic polling
- Persistent connection to server such as websocket or xmpp
- Push Notification

Do its publish subscribe works even when app is in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4.0, the PubNub iOS SDK does not receive subscription events when the app it is running in is suspended.  You can set up Push Notifications via PubNub's APNS gateway to receive push events, but they are handled like standard push notifications and not like PubNub events.

When your app is running, PubNub appears to use a websocket connection to send and receive notifications.  The client you create receives callbacks when messages are received on the channels you subscribe to.

Their SDK is open source, so you can inspect what is happening internally if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Mathew! I got the source but I just wanted to know what it uses, then I will look into source for details if needed. Does same thing happens in android too?

Comment: Publish/subscribe events will not work while the app is in suspension, but when the app is in background they will still work as long as you have some background modes on (such as a finite-length-background-task which gives you roughly 3 minutes of background time to allow code to continue executing)

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub and Background Connectivity

Staying connected in the background an continuing to receive realtime messages via `subscribe` is not a function of the PubNub SDK and it does not matter if you are using PubNub iOS 3.x SDK (please don't, it has EOL'ed) or [PubNub Objective-C for iOS 4.x SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4) (please start using this or migrate to it ASAP). You have to configure and implement your app to run in the background and Apple has to give you permission (via the app review) to do so.

Your app has to be of the type that justifies background activity: [see Apple dev docs for iPhone OS Programming Guide - Background Execution (table 3.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

There is a great tutorial at RayWunderlich.com on [Background Modes in iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) that does a great job of explaining all the options.

There is [PubNub Swift for iOS SDK 4.x](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk), as well.